# Problem to connect to TFS with user/password

Tags: rest, powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

When I try to connect to tfs the function Get-Data failed with 401 error although the function Get-DataWithCred succeed with the same argument.

And don't understand the difference with this two ?

```bsh
function Get-Data([string]$username, [string]$password, [string]$url) 
{
  # Step 1. Create a username:password pair
  $credPair = "$($username):$($password)"

  # Step 2. Encode the pair to Base64 string
  $encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))

  # Step 3. Form the header and add the Authorization attribute to it
  $headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials" }

  # Step 4. Make the GET request
  $responseData =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers
  return $responseData
}


function Get-DataWithCred([string]$username, [string]$password, [string]$url) 
{
  $p = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force

  $Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $p

  $responseData =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get  -Credential $Cred
  return $responseData
}
```

The purpose is too connect through tfs with python script who failed the same way that the function Get-Data when I use the requests library.

```py
>>> r = requests.get('https://tfs-url.com', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
401
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a microsoft way to pass your credential : the ntlm protocol.

This protocol are not supported by default by requests but a library [requests_ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm) extend requests by adding support to ntlm.

A simple example:

```py
import os
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth


def main():
    user = "user"
    password = "password"

    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(user, password)

    url = "https://tfs-url.com"

    response = session.get(url)

    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem with  $encodedCredentials.

Take a look at [Choosing the right authentication mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)

For my script who connect to TFS i use the following code :

```
     $strUser = 'domain\userID'
     $password = "YOURPASSWORD"
     $strPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
     $cred= New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($strUser, $strPass)
```

And than connect to the TFS as you did :

```
$responseData =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get  -Credential $cred
```

Or, If you would like to connect to the TFS with the user who runs the script you can use

`-UseDefaultCredentials`

code snippet :

```
$responseData =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get  -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Comment: thank, but it's don't respond to my question your method is the same that my function Get-DataWithCred. And I can't use this method in other language that powershell :(

Comment: So you want to connect tfs api via python ?

Comment: Yes sorry my question wasn't very comprehensible. I edited it.